# How can I define the array length using stdIn by Wayne

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, input, stdin

so for University we have been using the StdIn class by Wayne. 
Can anyone tell me how i am able to give the array "speicher" a length that matches the number of integers passed by a "input document".

```
public class xy {

public static void main(String[] args) {



    while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
    laenge ++;
    } 
    int x = 0;
    int speicher [] = new int [**?**];
    int q = 0;
    while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
        int value = StdIn.readInt();

                if (value != x){

                // StdOut.println(value);
                q ++;
                speicher [q] = value;
            }
         x = value;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < laenge +1; i ++) { 
    System.out.println (speicher [i]);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Since number of numbers is variabled, I would suggest using Java Collections, example LinkedList. Then convert that list to an array.

Comment: can you try to explain briefly? where is the input document ?